# How to get my terminal to open NeoVim with maximised window size using Openbox rc.xml key bindings?

Tags: gnome-terminal, openbox, nvim, maximize

I am using Openbox 3.6.1 windowing with Arch 5.6.4, 
 and NeoVim 0.4.3, with gnome-terminal 3.36.1. 
These are the most up to date versions.

I am currently sizing my gnome-terminal window using these lines within my NeoVim `.vimrc` file

```
set lines=36 columns=128
```

However this is not ideal becasue I frequently have different window layout needs.

What I want is for the window to open maximised, whatever my windowing layout.

On the gnome-terminal command line, the following command opens file `rc.xml` with nvim in the gnome-terminal, with maximised window as expected.

```
gnome-terminal --window --maximize -e "bash -c 'nvim /home/user/rc.xml'"
```

I dont usually open files with nvim this way though.

What I do is I call nvim in gnome terminal, using an Openbox key binding.

Here are 3 example key bindings I have tried within the `rc.xml` file ..

.. this keybinding opens the `rc.xml` file with nvim, but not with the maximised gnome-terminal window as needed ...

```
<keybind key="w-a-numbersign">
    <action name="Execute">
        <command>gnome-terminal --window --maximize -e "bash -c 'nvim /home/user/rc.xml'"</command>
    </action>
</keybind>
```

.. again .. this keybinding opens the `rc.xml` file with nvim, but not with the maximised gnome-terminal window as needed ...

```
<keybind key="w-a-numbersign">
                <action name="Execute"><command>gnome-terminal --window --maximize -e "/bin/bash -c '
                     nvim /home/user/rc.xml;
             exit;
             exec /bin/bash -i'"</command></action>
</keybind>
```

.. again .. this keybinding opens the `rc.xml` file with nvim, but not with the maximised gnome-terminal window as needed ...

```
<keybind key="w-a-numbersign">
      <action name="Execute"><command>/home/user/linux_config/script_vim/rc.xml.sh</command></action>
</keybind>
```

.. with the above script simply containing

```
#!/bin/bash
gnome-terminal --start-maximized -e \"bash -c 'nvim /home/user/rc.xml'\"
```

I am not aware of any parameter within my `.vimrc` file that is stopping the terminal window opening maximised.

Can anyone suggest how I can adjust my key binding to open this window maximised?

Answer (score 0):

I found a gnome terminal syntax that allows the Openbox key binding to open the window maximised

```
<keybind key="w-a-numbersign"><action name="Execute"><command>bash -c '
    gnome-terminal --window --maximize -e "nvim /home/user/rc.xml";
'</command></action></keybind>
```